# Unique array in Mongoose is not throwing error when same key is stored again

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I try to store friends in my friends collection. This collection contains a field userId which is an array of user ids. When I store the same id again I want mongoose to throw an error.

My friend schema looks like this:

```
const friendSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  userId: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
});
```

I am calling it like this:

```
Friends.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.userData.userId},  {$addToSet: { userId: req.body.id  } }, {safe:false, upsert: true}, function (error, friend) {
  if(error){
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'You already added this user as friend! ' +error,
    });
  }else if (!friend) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Authentication failed',
      });
  } else {
    Friends.
    find({_id: req.userData.userId})
      .populate('userId')
      .exec(function(error, posts) {
        if(!error) {
          let returnValue = [];
          posts.map((x)=>{
            returnValue = x.userId;
          })
          return res.status(200).json(returnValue);
        }else {
          return res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Could you please specify what is the error with the current code?

Comment: I can add the same ID several times to the userId array in the friend collection, although I have declared it unique